# Specify different timepoints for boundary conditions of Scipy's "odeint"?

Tags: python, scipy, ode

I am trying to numerically solve a system of two nonlinear ODEs. I am using Scipy's `odeint` function. `odeint` requires an argument `y0` which specify the initial conditions. However, it seems to assume that the initial conditions of `y0` begin at the same timepoint (i.e both conditions are at t=0). In my case, I want to specify two different boundary conditions that are specified for different times (i.e. omega(t=0) = 0, theta(t=100) = 0). I can't seem to figure out how to do this and would greatly appreciate any help!

Some example code below:

```
from scipy.integrate import odeint

def pend(y, t, b, c):
    theta, omega = y
    dydt = [omega, -b*omega - c*np.sin(theta)]
    return dydt

b = 0.25
c = 5.0
t = np.linspace(0, 100, 101)

# I want to make these initial conditions specified at different times
y0 = [0, 0]

sol = odeint(pend, y0, t, args=(b, c))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`odeint` solves the [*initial value problem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_value_problem).  The problem that you describe is a two-point [*boundary value problem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_value_problem).  For that, you can use [`scipy.integrate.solve_bvp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_bvp.html)

You could also take a look at [`scikits.bvp1lg`](https://github.com/pv/scikits.bvp1lg/) and [`scikits.bvp_solver`](https://pypi.org/project/scikits.bvp_solver/#description), although it looks like `bvp_solver` hasn't been updated in a long time.

For example, here is how you could use `scipy.integrate.solve_bvp`.  I changed the parameters so the solution does not decay so fast and has a lower frequency.  With b = 0.25, the decay is rapid enough that θ(100) ≈ 0 for all solutions where ω(0) = 0 and |θ(0)| is on the order of 1.

The function `bc` will be passed the values of [θ(t), ω(t)] at t=0 and t=100.  It must return two values that are the "residuals" of the boundary conditions.  That just means it must compute values that must be 0.  In your case, just return `y0[1]` (which is ω(0))  and `y1[0]` (which is θ(100)).  (If the boundary condition at t=0 had been, say `ω(0) = 1`, the first element of the return value of `bc` would be `y0[1] - 1`.)

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_bvp, odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def pend(t, y, b, c):
    theta, omega = y
    dydt = [omega, -b*omega - c*np.sin(theta)]
    return dydt


def bc(y0, y1, b, c):
    # Values at t=0:
    theta0, omega0 = y0

    # Values at t=100:  
    theta1, omega1 = y1

    # These return values are what we want to be 0:
    return [omega0, theta1]


b = 0.02
c = 0.08

t = np.linspace(0, 100, 201)

# Use the solution to the initial value problem as the initial guess
# for the BVP solver. (This is probably not necessary!  Other, simpler
# guesses might also work.)
ystart = odeint(pend, [1, 0], t, args=(b, c,), tfirst=True)


result = solve_bvp(lambda t, y: pend(t, y, b=b, c=c),
                   lambda y0, y1: bc(y0, y1, b=b, c=c),
                   t, ystart.T)


plt.figure(figsize=(6.5, 3.5))
plt.plot(result.x, result.y[0], label=r'$\theta(t)$')
plt.plot(result.x, result.y[1], '--', label=r'$\omega(t)$')
plt.xlabel('t')
plt.grid()
plt.legend(framealpha=1, shadow=True)
plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

Here's the plot of the result, where you can see that ω(0) = 0 and θ(100) = 0.

[image: plot]

Note that the solution to the boundary value problem is not unique.  If we modify the creation `ystart` to

```
ystart = odeint(pend, [np.pi, 0], t, args=(b, c,), tfirst=True)
```

a different solution is found, as seen in the following plot:

[image: plot2]

In this solution, the pendulum starts out *almost* at the inverted position (`result.y[0, 0] = 3.141592653578858`).  It starts to fall *very slowly*; gradually it falls faster, and it reaches the straight down position at t = 100.

The trivial solution θ(t) ≡ 0 and ω(t) ≡ 0 also satisfies the boundary conditions.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I am a bit confused about where the boundary conditions are specified `y0` and `y1` (i.e. if I wanted to change the conditions so that ω(0) = 1?)

Comment: I updated the answer with some more comments about `bc`.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for the very helpful answer!

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser, I have been watching your answer o this topic. I have an issue with my particular case. It  will not worth a new question, Is there any way to make a discussion in a room here in StackOVerflow?